# removing tag name but keep tag

Tags: javascript, html, tags

Hello I have a `<strong></strong>` Tag nested in a paragraph `<p></p>`, I'm trying to remove the `<strong>` tag but keep the text or the value. Something similar to unwrapping in jquery but in javascript.

I tried this code on a dummy HTML page and it works fine

```html
<html>
<body>
    <p>aaa <Strong>bbbbb</Strong></p>
    <p>acccaa <Strong>ddddd</Strong></p>
    <p>eeee <Strong>ffff</Strong></p>

    <script>
        var p = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
        for(var i=0;i<p.length;i++){
            var strongs = p[i].getElementsByTagName("strong");
            for(var j=0;j<strongs.length;j++){
                p[i].replaceChild(document.createTextNode(strongs[j].innerText),strongs[j]);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But as soon as I try the same code on a real page example: https://www.bustle.com/privacy

I get this error:

> Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': The node to be replaced is not a child of this node.

Any idea on how to get this to work on the example or any other example?

Comment: Given that example page, you have `<p>` tags that don't contain `<strong>` tags hence the error on a live page.

Comment: On you page, `contact us` is not immediate children of p. It is a child of anchor tag `<a>`. Therefore it gives an error on that page. And this may exists at several place too. It is just an example here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName()` returns a *live* NodeList. So when you replace a tag, the indexes of all the following elements shift down and the code fails when you have more than one `<strong>` tag in the same paragraph. As a result, it will skip some tags.

The solution is to convert the `NodeList` to an array so it doesn't change while you're looping.

Another problem in your real page that isn't in the snippet is that the `<strong>` tags can be nested deeply within the `<p>`. You should use `strongs[j].parentElement` to get its direct parent, rather than assuming that the `p[i]` is the parent.

```js
var p = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
  var strongs = Array.from(p[i].getElementsByTagName("strong"));
  for (var j = 0; j < strongs.length; j++) {
    strongs[j].parentElement.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(strongs[j].innerText), strongs[j]);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <p>aaa
    <Strong>bbbbb</Strong> - <strong>12345</strong></p>
  <p>acccaa <span><Strong>ddddd</Strong> x</span></p>
  <p>eeee
    <Strong>ffff</Strong>
  </p>

</body>

</html>
```

You can also avoid the nested loops by using a query selector.

```js
var strongs = document.querySelectorAll("p strong");
strongs.forEach(strong => strong.parentElement.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(strong.innerText), strong));
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <p>aaa
    <Strong>bbbbb</Strong> - <strong>12345</strong></p>
  <p>acccaa <span><Strong>ddddd</Strong> x</span></p>
  <p>eeee
    <Strong>ffff</Strong>
  </p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I didn't think of the fact of the shifting of indexes, thank you very much

Comment: Many thanks for the elegant code that you added, I'm new to js, for your time I'm accepting this solution.

Answer (score 0):

No need to loop through paragraphs to remove `<strong>`. Simply removing all 'strongs' in place works fine.

```js
function removeStrongs() {
  let strongs = document.querySelectorAll('strong');
  strongs.forEach(strong => {
    strong.insertAdjacentText('afterend', strong.innerText);
    strong.remove();
  });
}
```

```html
<h4>This is a <strong>Title</strong></h4>
<p>
  Now is the time for all <strong>good</strong> men to come to the <strong>aid</strong> of the party.
</p>
<p>A <strong>quick brown</strong> fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>

<button onclick="removeStrongs();">Remove Strongs</button>
```

Comment: Thank you @terrymorse.